# How to get the numeric code of all ISO 3166-1 countries in C#

Tags: c#, iso-3166

I need to get the numeric codes of [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) countries in C#.

[image: Screenshot of table listing countries and their numeric codes]

It seems with the [`RegionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx) class I can only get the Alpha2 and Alpha3 codes.  Is it possible to get the ISO 3166-1 numeric codes in C#?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such a information in the framework...well, maybe in some low-level API, though.

However, why don't put the codes inside a text file and parse them by C# code?

I done the same thing for the Alpha-2 codes.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a extension method for RegionInfo in order to retrieve the numeric value. 
It's similar to the solution mentioned by Dmitry Bychenko, but I need an extension method and I want a current version of the iso 3166 records:

```
            //usage
        RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo("US");
        int numericIsoCodeUS = regionInfo.NumericIsoCode();
```

Extension method class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ISO3166_1Test
{
    public static class Iso3166Helper
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, int> Iso3166NumericDictionary { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// This is an extension method for class RegionInfo
        /// It will return the ISO 3166-1 numeric value of a given RegionInfo
        /// 
        /// If there is no numeric value for a given regionInfo(e.g. Serbia and Montenegro (Former) or Caribbean), and exception will be thrown
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="regionInfo">The RegionInfo object used for the extension method</param>
        /// <returns>the numeric ISO 31666-1 value of a given RegionInfo </returns>
        public static int NumericIsoCode(this RegionInfo regionInfo)
        {
            if (!Iso3166NumericDictionary.ContainsKey(regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName))
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("There is no numeric value for regionInfo {0}", regionInfo.Name));
            }
            return Iso3166NumericDictionary[regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName];
        }
        static Iso3166Helper()
        {
            Iso3166NumericDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>{
                {"AF", 4},
                {"AX", 248},
                {"AL", 8},
                {"DZ", 12},
                {"AS", 16},
                {"AD", 20},
                {"AO", 24},
                {"AI", 660},
                {"AQ", 10},
                {"AG", 28},
                {"AR", 32},
                {"AM", 51},
                {"AW", 533},
                {"AU", 36},
                {"AT", 40},
                {"AZ", 31},
                {"BS", 44},
                {"BH", 48},
                {"BD", 50},
                {"BB", 52},
                {"BY", 112},
                {"BE", 56},
                {"BZ", 84},
                {"BJ", 204},
                {"BM", 60},
                {"BT", 64},
                {"BO", 68},
                {"BQ", 535},
                {"BA", 70},
                {"BW", 72},
                {"BV", 74},
                {"BR", 76},
                {"IO", 86},
                {"BN", 96},
                {"BG", 100},
                {"BF", 854},
                {"BI", 108},
                {"KH", 116},
                {"CM", 120},
                {"CA", 124},
                {"CV", 132},
                {"KY", 136},
                {"CF", 140},
                {"TD", 148},
                {"CL", 152},
                {"CN", 156},
                {"CX", 162},
                {"CC", 166},
                {"CO", 170},
                {"KM", 174},
                {"CG", 178},
                {"CD", 180},
                {"CK", 184},
                {"CR", 188},
                {"CI", 384},
                {"HR", 191},
                {"CU", 192},
                {"CW", 531},
                {"CY", 196},
                {"CZ", 203},
                {"DK", 208},
                {"DJ", 262},
                {"DM", 212},
                {"DO", 214},
                {"EC", 218},
                {"EG", 818},
                {"SV", 222},
                {"GQ", 226},
                {"ER", 232},
                {"EE", 233},
                {"ET", 231},
                {"FK", 238},
                {"FO", 234},
                {"FJ", 242},
                {"FI", 246},
                {"FR", 250},
                {"GF", 254},
                {"PF", 258},
                {"TF", 260},
                {"GA", 266},
                {"GM", 270},
                {"GE", 268},
                {"DE", 276},
                {"GH", 288},
                {"GI", 292},
                {"GR", 300},
                {"GL", 304},
                {"GD", 308},
                {"GP", 312},
                {"GU", 316},
                {"GT", 320},
                {"GG", 831},
                {"GN", 324},
                {"GW", 624},
                {"GY", 328},
                {"HT", 332},
                {"HM", 334},
                {"VA", 336},
                {"HN", 340},
                {"HK", 344},
                {"HU", 348},
                {"IS", 352},
                {"IN", 356},
                {"ID", 360},
                {"IR", 364},
                {"IQ", 368},
                {"IE", 372},
                {"IM", 833},
                {"IL", 376},
                {"IT", 380},
                {"JM", 388},
                {"JP", 392},
                {"JE", 832},
                {"JO", 400},
                {"KZ", 398},
                {"KE", 404},
                {"KI", 296},
                {"KP", 408},
                {"KR", 410},
                {"KW", 414},
                {"KG", 417},
                {"LA", 418},
                {"LV", 428},
                {"LB", 422},
                {"LS", 426},
                {"LR", 430},
                {"LY", 434},
                {"LI", 438},
                {"LT", 440},
                {"LU", 442},
                {"MO", 446},
                {"MK", 807},
                {"MG", 450},
                {"MW", 454},
                {"MY", 458},
                {"MV", 462},
                {"ML", 466},
                {"MT", 470},
                {"MH", 584},
                {"MQ", 474},
                {"MR", 478},
                {"MU", 480},
                {"YT", 175},
                {"MX", 484},
                {"FM", 583},
                {"MD", 498},
                {"MC", 492},
                {"MN", 496},
                {"ME", 499},
                {"MS", 500},
                {"MA", 504},
                {"MZ", 508},
                {"MM", 104},
                {"NA", 516},
                {"NR", 520},
                {"NP", 524},
                {"NL", 528},
                {"NC", 540},
                {"NZ", 554},
                {"NI", 558},
                {"NE", 562},
                {"NG", 566},
                {"NU", 570},
                {"NF", 574},
                {"MP", 580},
                {"NO", 578},
                {"OM", 512},
                {"PK", 586},
                {"PW", 585},
                {"PS", 275},
                {"PA", 591},
                {"PG", 598},
                {"PY", 600},
                {"PE", 604},
                {"PH", 608},
                {"PN", 612},
                {"PL", 616},
                {"PT", 620},
                {"PR", 630},
                {"QA", 634},
                {"RE", 638},
                {"RO", 642},
                {"RU", 643},
                {"RW", 646},
                {"BL", 652},
                {"SH", 654},
                {"KN", 659},
                {"LC", 662},
                {"MF", 663},
                {"PM", 666},
                {"VC", 670},
                {"WS", 882},
                {"SM", 674},
                {"ST", 678},
                {"SA", 682},
                {"SN", 686},
                {"RS", 688},
                {"SC", 690},
                {"SL", 694},
                {"SG", 702},
                {"SX", 534},
                {"SK", 703},
                {"SI", 705},
                {"SB", 90},
                {"SO", 706},
                {"ZA", 710},
                {"GS", 239},
                {"SS", 728},
                {"ES", 724},
                {"LK", 144},
                {"SD", 729},
                {"SR", 740},
                {"SJ", 744},
                {"SZ", 748},
                {"SE", 752},
                {"CH", 756},
                {"SY", 760},
                {"TW", 158},
                {"TJ", 762},
                {"TZ", 834},
                {"TH", 764},
                {"TL", 626},
                {"TG", 768},
                {"TK", 772},
                {"TO", 776},
                {"TT", 780},
                {"TN", 788},
                {"TR", 792},
                {"TM", 795},
                {"TC", 796},
                {"TV", 798},
                {"UG", 800},
                {"UA", 804},
                {"AE", 784},
                {"GB", 826},
                {"US", 840},
                {"UM", 581},
                {"UY", 858},
                {"UZ", 860},
                {"VU", 548},
                {"VE", 862},
                {"VN", 704},
                {"VG", 92},
                {"VI", 850},
                {"WF", 876},
                {"EH", 732},
                {"YE", 887},
                {"ZM", 894},
                {"ZW", 716}

                };
        }
    }
}
```